# getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException in a seemingly right code

Tags: mockito

I have a `when` call like this :

```
    @Mock
    private MyEventFactory myEventFactory;

    @Mock 
    private MyEvent myEvent;
when(myEventFactory.createMyEvent(anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject(),anyObject())).thenReturn(myEvent);
```

However I get an exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
```

> MyEventFactory is an interface

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: Can you please show us your whole test method? Mockito uses static state, so it's unfortunately the case with Mockito and InvalidUseOfMatchersException that there can be test pollution from earlier statements or other tests.

Comment: can you please specify what parameters Your providing to createMyEvent() method

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the mocks?  It would help to see the full code posted, but I suspect you need to call something like

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

before you run your `when` statement.  This article shows an example: https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-mock-initmocks/

Comment: I have already posted the relevant parts. I am initializing the mocks and configuring them through when(). Thats it. The event factory has a method createEvent() as shown

Comment: Perhaps you could comment out all the other stuff--all the non-relevant parts we can't see here--and run the test.  Do you get the same failure?